# adding dynamic column kendo ui treelist

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

Is it possible to add a dynamic column in kendo UI treelist, I have seen [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/dynamically-add-new-column) post which is quite old, it says its not supported in kendo UI library.

Other alternate is destroy and recreate the kendo UI TreeList, but I am applying many css and data changes on TreeList so recreating will be a lot of effort bcs I will have to track these changes and re apply them.

I would like to know if there is any other solution then re creating the kendo UI TreeList.

Comment: Kendo's Treelist and Grid are two different things.  You are referring to both of them in your question

Comment: I have modified my question.

Answer (score 0):

Set the necessary columns at initialization phase and hide the not required ones. Then show them when necessary, see this Dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@mrtaunus/EFUva

If this does not resolve your issue, please clarify your intent and scenario.